# Binding Qt with java

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

How can I bind Qt with java by java `java native interface`?

I want to make an java app but for UI i want to use Qt, for some reason I can not use `qt-jambi` so I need to bind Qt with java.

Is it possible to create an Qt app in Qt creator and bind this component to java through `java native interface`?

If some one knows How `qt-jambi` works, please tell me, so help!

In fact my general question is that how (if its possible) to make a java app that some of its component like UI is written in c++? I do not want to use only one c++ method or library, I want to use I complete c++ qt app.

Thank you! 
sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have a hybrid Qt/Java application in which you use Qt API in Java code, definitely the best option is to use Qt Jambi. JNI only lets you to call some Java function from C++ world or vice-versa.

Qt Jambi enables you to  to write software in Java in the speed of natively executable code and with native look and feel on different supported platforms. Actually it is a Java binding to Qt, so you can easily use Qt API in Java. There are some documentations on the web about it like [this](http://qtjambi.org/documentation) or [that](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-index.html).